# Attribute Error Python

Tags: python

I'm having a python problem with a simple program. The program is supposed to allow the user to make a make a Cow() instance and give the cow a name in the parameter.

```
class Cow():
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        if self.name == None:
            raise NoNameCowError("Your cow must have a name")


    def speak(self):
        print self.name, "says moo"
```

Now when I do

```
cow.Cow("Toby")
```

I get the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#32>", line 1, in <module>
    cow.Cow("Toby")
  File "C:\Users\Samga_000\Documents\MyPrograms\cow.py", line 8, in __init__
    self.name = name
AttributeError: Cow instance has no attribute 'name'
```

Help? I originally thought I did something wrong with the exception but it doesn't seem to be that. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Working as it should. Apart from that: your code does not trigger speak(). You are lying about what you are doing and your code.

Comment: Your current code looks good, please try reloading the module or remove the `cow.pyc` file and try again.

Comment: Your program is incomplete, leading many people to guess what the problem is. Please provide a short, complete program that demonstrates the error. Please copy-paste (do not retype) the program and its output, and please decribe your expected output. See http://SSCCE.ORG for more information.

Answer (score 1):

I think you modified your source code and didn't reloaded the module:

Buggy version:

```
class Cow():
    def __init__(self, name):
        if self.name == None:
            raise NoNameCowError("Your cow must have a name")
    def speak(self):
        print self.name, "says moo"

>>> import so
```

Error raised as expected:

```
>>> so.Cow('abc1')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-4-80383f90b571>", line 1, in <module>
    so.Cow('abc1')
  File "so.py", line 3, in __init__
    if self.name == None:
AttributeError: Cow instance has no attribute 'name'
```

Now let's modify the source code and add this line `self.name = name`:

```
>>> import so
>>> so.Cow('abc1')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-6-80383f90b571>", line 1, in <module>
    so.Cow('abc1')
  File "so.py", line 3, in __init__
    self.name = name
AttributeError: Cow instance has no attribute 'name'
```

eh! still same error? That's because python is still using the old `.pyc` file or the cached module object. Just reload the module and updated code works fine:

```
>>> reload(so)
<module 'so' from 'so.py'>
>>> so.Cow('dsfds')
<so.Cow instance at 0x8b78e8c>
```

From [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#more-on-modules):

> Note For efficiency reasons, each module is only imported once per
>   interpreter session. Therefore, if you change your modules, you must
>   restart the interpreter – or, if it’s just one module you want to test
>   interactively, use `reload()`, e.g. `reload(modulename)`.

---

A better version of your code:

```
class Cow():
    def __init__(self, name=None):   #Use a default value 
        self.name = name
        if self.name is None:        #use `is` for testing against `None`
            raise NoNameCowError("Your cow must have a name")
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm staring at the name check; this object requires the name argument does it not?

```
if self.name == None:
        raise NoNameCowError("Your cow must have a name")
```

I'm a little Python thick, but that looks like a required arg.

Answer (score 0):

When your declaring Cow, you need to pass object in the parentheses:

```
class Cow(object):
    rest of code.
```

This way Python knows the class your declaring is an object with attributes and methods.